# ProgressBar not updating on screen despite NotifyPropertyChanged working correctly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, progress-bar, ui-thread

First off, sorry for the length of the question.

I am updating a Silverlight for Windows Phone 7 app which currently stores data in multiple XML files. I am updating the app to use a CompactSQL DB and I have to migrate the data from the XML files into the DB upon first run after installing the new version.

I want a progress bar (IsIndeterminate=false) showing the user the progress as each file is migrated to the DB (as the operation can take up to 2 minutes).

The problem is that the progressbar is not updating (or even showing up) on the screen despite the NotifyProperyChanged event firing off and updating the bar's Value correctly. When I set the Value in XAML it appears fine (static - but at least it's drawn on the screen).

I do not know why the progressbar does not show up on the device at all.

My INotifyChanged setup

```
private int migrateCount;
public int MigrateCount //Prop used for ProgressBar.Value
{
    get
    {
        return this.migrateCount;
    }
    set
    {
        this.migrateCount = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("MigrateCount");
    }
}

public int MigrateTotal { get; set; } //Prop used for ProgressBar.Maximum

public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

void MainPage_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "MigrateCount")
    { 
        ProBar.Maximum = MigrateTotal; //ProBar is the name of my ProgressBar
        ProBar.Value = MigrateCount;
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public MainPage()
{
    this.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(MainPage_PropertyChanged);
    ...
}
```

Calling the MigrateDB method in Loaded rather than OnNavigatedTo because OS terminates any app that takes too long to load.

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            string[] dirs = store.GetDirectoryNames();
            if (dirs.Length > 1) //Checks to see if there's any data to migrate 
            {
                MigrateDB();
                LoadData(); //Loads data from the DB once it's populated
            }
        }
```

This operation takes ages. Approximately 100 XML files per minute and I expect users to have between 30 and 300 files.

```
private void MigrateDB()
{
    string[] DirList;
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        DirList = store.GetDirectoryNames("*");
        MigrateTotal = DirList.Length - 1; // -1 to account for the "Shared" Dir
        foreach(...)
        {
           ... Does lots of IsoStore operations / XML serialising and DB updating
           MigrateCount++;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it all working. As mentioned by others, the UI thread was being blocked and I needed to transfer the CPU intensive code to another thread. This freed up the UI (main) thread to update the progressbar. I did that by making the following changes

- Deleting all the INotifyPropertyChanged code.
- Implemending the BackgroundWorker Class by following this MSDN tutorial [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).
- I wrapped the MigrateDB method code inside the BackgroundWorker.DoWork event, and
- Updated my ProgressBar.Value in the BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged event.

This is my final working code with changes:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage

private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

...

public MainPage()
    {
       ...

        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        ...
    }

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadData(); //LINQ2SQL queries to display DB
    }

    void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        double total = 0;
        double count = 0;
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        ... 
        foreach(...)
        {
           ... Does lots of IsoStore operations / XML serialising / DB updating
           count++;
           double cntr = count / total * 100;
           worker.ReportProgress((int)cntr);
        }
    }

private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         ...
         bw.RunWorkerAsync();
         ...
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved if you will work on another Thread as the Progressbar is allowed to draw his progress on User interface. If you are working in the MainThread like it seems to look like, and your progressbar is waiting for any idle situation to be allowed to draw to the user interface, that can take a long time if you have CPU consuming methodes.

[image: Multithreading]

The answer of the solution is simple; drop your database reader into its own thread.
The solution as software can be easy too if you use:
`ThreadStart()` to put your reader in Thread and `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to display the progressbar values on GUI.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/7003

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks, I thought it might've been something to do with threading however I was at a loss of how it all worked. I ended up fixing it with the BackgroundWorker Class, but I wouldn't have found it without your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a threding problem. If you update the progress bar in the main process, it's not possible to update it. Maybe that it will update at the end of the function when alwais is finish.
I don't know if in win phone exists but try to use a background worker